# search database table for value and put it in a datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, search

I have a textbox and a search button i trying to search file names in a database table and display them in a datatable...

```
private void GetSearchResults(string machineID, string searchFileName)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SumooHAgentDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT FileID, BuFileName FROM BackedUpFiles WHERE BuFileName Like '%@searchFileName%' AND MachineID=@machineID", connection);
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@machineID", machineID);

    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchFileName", searchFileName);

    sqlDa.Fill(dt);
}
```

everything is working fine except that the searchFileName is not working in the query...

I tried putting just a value to check like

```
SELECT FileID, BuFileName FROM BackedUpFiles WHERE BuFileName Like '%b%' AND MachineID=@machineID
```

and i got the file values...

any suggestions..??

Comment: Have you tried stepping through in a debugger? What is the value of searchFileName when the function is called?

Comment: You also need `using` blocks around the `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your variable inside of a string, which is telling the database to search for the literal string '@searchFileName'.  To use the value of the variable, try this

```
'%' + @searchFileName + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need:

```
private void GetSearchResults(string machineID, string searchFileName)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SumooHAgentDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT FileID, BuFileName FROM BackedUpFiles WHERE BuFileName Like @searchFileName AND MachineID=@machineID", connection);
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@machineID", machineID);

    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchFileName", String.Format("%{0}%",searchFileName);

    sqlDa.Fill(dt);
}
```

I've run into this before. For some reason, it doesn't know how to parse out the parameters if it's in quotes. I guess it thinks it's a literal.

Comment: How would you search for `@` in a database if your dbms recognized it as a variable every time?

Answer (score 1):

try this one in your select

```
SELECT FileID, BuFileName FROM BackedUpFiles where REGEXP_LIKE(upper(BuFileName ),UPPER(@searchFileName)) AND MachineID=@machineID;
```